# Как изменить запись в базе данных Django по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: python, django

Я создаю проект на Django, и хочу добавить лайки и дизлайки, и у меня вопрос: как изменить запись в базе данных по нажатию кнопки?

Код:

```
# models.py:

from django.db import models
from datetime import date


class Tutorials(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField('Text')
    likes = models.IntegerField('Likes', default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField('Dislikes', default=0)
    date = models.DateField('Date', default=date.today())
    author = models.CharField('Author', max_length=16)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} {self.date}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tutorial'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tutorials'


<!-- HTML -->
{% for i in tutorials %}
        <div class="tutorial-block">
            <h1>{{ i.title }}</h1>
            <div class="tutorial-block-inner">
                <p>by {{ i.author }}</p>
                <p>{{ i.description }}</p>
                <p>{{ i.text }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tutorial-info">
                {{ i.likes }} <button onclick=""><img id="like-img" src="{% static 'root/img/thumbs-up-solid.svg' %}"></button> {{ i.dislikes }} <button><img id="dislike-img" src="{% static 'root/img/thumbs-down-solid.svg' %}"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: читали ли вы [подобные](https://evileg.com/en/post/246/) туториалы ?

Comment: @IchBinUser Вы не сможете запустить функцию питон при нажатии кнопки, т.к. кнопка нажимается на стороне клиента и к Вам приходит GET или POST запрос, если Вы это реализуете на javascript или сделаете форму с SUBMIT

Comment: @Виктор Как тогда сделать возможность ставить лайки?

Comment: @IchBinUser делайте на кнопке onclick  вызов функции javascript и отсылайте информацию по AJAX технологии с помощью javascript

Comment: если без аякса, то можно сделать отдельный эндпоинт на лайк/дизлайк, который будете уже дергать непосредственно из шаблона. могу написать подробнее, если интересно